# Why is my player still 'out of position' with 10 Chemistry in FIFA 1'4?

Tags: fifa-14

I have a CM Wilshere playing in CAM. He has 10 chemistry already, but still has a yellow circle below his card (i.e. telling me that he is slightly out of position). Since he has 10 chemistry is there any benefit to me using a position change on him to make him a CAM?

Comment: ive got to say this I hate UT in fifa 14 because of the handicap. Ive got top of the shelf players in my 2 gold teams. Spent £60+ on the UT itself and whenever i play someone with a worse team than mine (which is 99% of the time) my players are super slow, can't pass, their reaction time is super slow etc. I have changed the positions from CM to CAM RM to RW etc and have a 10 chemistry for each player , 100% overall team chemistry it doesnt seem to help. When I use a third gold team I have with mid range players , out of position and poor chemistry they seem to be extremely good! how ironic

Comment: Don't spend real money on FUT, the occasional loss isn't that bad. Also, just playing games makes you enough money to get good teams. Make sure you know how you want to play and buy the best players for your technique, not the best players on the game.

Answer (score 1):

Applying a "CM >>> CAM" position change will cause the player to have full chemistry, but will not really show a noticeable change to his overall playing style. If you want to change this aspect, apply a playing style to the player and he'll then have better attributes in certain areas. For example, you could apply the "Hunter" playing style, increasing the player's pace. Hope this helps!